# Aesthetic Distro

Tags: theme, window

In windows, whenever you change the wallpaper, all the themes and settings of programs and windows border change accordingly providing a pleasant and aesthetic look. Kindly suggest me a linux distro/package that provides the same pleasing experience.

**Edited**

I needed to switch to linux to take care of vital computationally packages that unfortunately do not work in kubuntu.

I want a linux package/setting/distro that automatically changes the theme of desktop, icons, windows borders based on background image and color, without me manually looking after the process just like in windows.

Comment: This is purely subjective. I find windows to offer an intensely displeasing experience, always, without exception, though not as displeasing as osx, regardless of the wallpaper. KDE may be the one you're looking for, but this is totally subjective, I don't personally like kde, or their graphics,  I like xfce, but you wouldn't like it. It's an excellent idea when moving into the world of free software to not try to get a drop in replacement for windows, which is totally non free, and thus not comparable in anyway to a free desktop. if you want windows, windows is probably what you should use.

Comment: kubuntu is 'linux'. I think you might want to spend some time clarifying your priorities before posting a vague subjective question like this. If you need a certain distribution to run your packages, then the packages are what are most important, not eye candy. Questions like this can't be answered which is why nobody  has so far offered an answer. Again, if you want windows, and insist you need a certain feature that windows has, then you want to be using windows, which is non free, non open source software, not gnu/linux, which is pretty much free top to bottom. Learn what matters.